# Problem with mapping an array of objects in Swift

Tags: swift, mapping

I have the following 2 class / structs:

```swift
class ConversationDetails {

    var messages: [ChatMessage]?
    var participants: [User]?
}

class User: Codable {

    init (email: String) {
        self.email = email
    }

    // system
    var id: String?
    var verifiedaccount: Int?
    var rejected: Int?
    ...
}
```

I've further got the `var conversationDetails = ConversationDetails ()` and I'm populating it with an API call. That all works fine.

I'd like to map the participants array in`conversationDetails`and access the id property of each participant like so:

```swift
let recipient_ids = self.conversationDetails.participants.map( { (participant) -> String in
           return participant.id
        })
```

In my understanding, map iterates over the entire participants array, which is an array of User objects and I can access each item via `participant`.
However, I get `Value of type '[User]' has no member 'id'` for `return participant.id`.

Where is my misunderstanding?

Comment: You should probably not use optional arrays here, unless you have a specific semantic difference between `nil` and `[]` that you want to preserve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `participants` var is optional, so you need to add question mark to access array. Without it, you try to call `map` on optional.

This is working code:

```
let recipientIds = conversationDetails.participants?.map( { (participant) -> String in
    return participant.id
})
```

or shorter:

`let recipientIds = conversationDetails.participants?.map { $0.id }`

Also, you can use `compactMap` to remove nils from `recipientIds` array and have `[String]` array instead of `[String?]`:

`let recipientIds = conversationDetails.participants?.compactMap { $0.id }`

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Maybe it's just me but didn't find the error message very conclusive...

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that `participants` is optional so you need to add a ? when accessing it

```
conversationDetails.participants?
```

then when mapping you should use `compactMap` since `id` is also an optional property

```
let recipient_ids = conversationDetails.participants?.compactMap { $0.id }
```

Another variant is to not have an optional array but instead initialize it to an empty array. This is actually a much better way to handle collection properties because you can have a cleaner code by initializing them to an empty collection

```
var participants = [User]()
```

and then do

```
let recipient_ids = conversationDetails.participants.compactMap { $0.id }
```